# EditText is gone but values remain in memory

Tags: android

I have a couple of EditTexts arranged on rows and columns.Those EditTexts contain product name,quantity and price and a TextView that shows the total in real time(calculates it each time you write on one of the EditTexts)
I've setup a a button on each row that when clicked sets visibility of the row(3EditTexts for product name,price and quantity) to GONE.
My problem is that after i set the visibility to GONE,though there are no more EditTexts it still calculates their values from before being GONE.

My question now is,what happens when the EditTexts are set to visibility.GONE ?
My app calculates in real time,so when something happens to an EditText,he calculates again..but it's like the values are still there...Isn't this supposed to be the difference between invisible and gone ?

I'll show you the way i calculate(it is called even after you press the X button to erase the EditTexts,not only when you change values inside EditTexts)

```
public void calculeaza() {

    totaltest = 0;
    prod = new String[allprod.size()];
    pret = new String[allpret.size()];
    cant = new String[allcant.size()];

    for (int m = 0; m < allprod.size(); m++) {

        prod[m] = allprod.get(m).getText().toString();
        if (prod[m].matches("")) {
            prod[m] = "    -    ";

        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {

        cant[j] = allcant.get(j).getText().toString();
        if (cant[j].matches("")) {
            cant[j] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < allpret.size(); k++) {
        pret[k] = allpret.get(k).getText().toString();
        if (pret[k].matches("")) {
            pret[k] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < allpret.size(); l++) {

        Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);

        totaltest = totaltest + temp;

        TextView totalf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        totalf.setText(String.format("Total: %.2f", totaltest));

    }
}
```

Comment: try setting `edittext.setText("")` before setting visibility to Gone.

Comment: Yes,i've already done that,thanks but my question still ramains : why was that happening ? Do GONE views still remain in the memory or something like that ?

Comment: i don't see that statement in the above code. Also why are you initializing this  `TextView totalf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total)` in for loop. you can move that part outside the for loop. move the initialization inside `oncreate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines  Straight from Android dev site..

```
View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
```

i.e it retains `EditText` object even after `Gone`..

You can reinitialise edittext if you dont want it to retain its value...or `setText = ""`

Above quoted is the only difference...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Oh,i see,should've checked on that before writing here,heh.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really seeing in the code you posted anything I can use to answer this question, but there does appear to be some confusion as to what setVisibility does:

INVISIBLE elements are not seen on the page, but they still take up space (there's a hole where they would be)

GONE elements have no visible effect on the screen, from the user's perspective they aren't there.  However they are still part of the view.

If you want to remove the object from the view, then you need to call removeView() on its parent.

It may still take up memory after it has been removed from the view, in case your code has kept references to it in any variables.

It may still take up memory after there are no further references to it, at least until the garbage collector gets around to it.

I'm hoping the rather generalized statements above help clarify the situation.